# Insert calendar using google calendar api v3 occurring this error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use Google calendar api to create new calendar. I am facing this error while requesting to create calendar. What's am I doing wrong here:

```
        Calendar newCalendar = new Calendar { Summary = "DropcueCalendar"};

        string Url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars";
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        request.Method = "POST";   
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + newToken.access_token);

        string param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newCalendar);
        byte[] bs = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(param);

        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
        }
        // error occurring here during request.GetResponse() call
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            sr.Close();
        }
```

N.B:  "newToken" is the authenticated token.